# Need to change the background color of icon inside extjs grid action column

Tags: extjs, gridpanel

I need to change the background color of icon inside extjs grid action column on clicking that icon.

```
 handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                   //Need to change the background color of the delete icon
                }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mohansee/6afxy/2/

Comment: it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/Jandalf/6afxy/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will do it:

```
handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
    Ext.query('td.x-action-col-cell img',grid.getNode(rowIndex))[0].style.setProperty('background-color','#000')
}
```

Comment: @MohanSee: don't know why nobody accepted your edit, but I changed it, sorry about forgetting the rowIndex.