# Need to change the icon when a icon inside extjs grid action column is clicked

Tags: extjs, gridpanel

I **need to change the background color of icon inside extjs grid action column on clicking that icon.**

```
handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
               //Need to change the delete icon with add icon
            }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mohansee/6afxy/6/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to change the background color of icon inside extjs grid action column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122820/need-to-change-the-background-color-of-icon-inside-extjs-grid-action-column)

Comment: if that is the case can anyone of you guys can make that fiddle to work.

Comment: @MohanSee see my comment on that question

Comment: sorry guys question updated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var deleteBttn = Ext.query('td.x-action-col-cell img',grid.getNode(rowIndex))[0];
   deleteBttn.src = 'http://etf-prod-projects-1415177589.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/trac/docasu/export/2/trunk/client/extjs/shared/icons/fam/add.gif';
```

By adding the above code in the handler section fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine if you are not in paging grid or on the same page in the paging grid, it doesn't work for the paging grid.

Comment: it happened for everything. Nothing to do with pagination.